# Intel RST driver - magic performance boost (only) up till version 11.2.0?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, sata, intel-rst

what's the magic behind the massive write speed performance boost by intel RST drivers up till and including version 11.2.0?

i have done some performance measurements of my application that is *extreme heavily writing to the HDD* (it is *indirectly* making `FlushFileBuffers` getting called in a very thight loop).

the testing has been carried out on different environments and also with different drivers.

[image: performance measurements]

## the results are:

on environments with above mentioned RST drivers the "overall" application performance is **5 times** higher - compared against the other environments that have either:

- HDD running in legacy IDE mode
- AHCI with generic microsoft drivers
- AHCI with intel RST drivers later than 11.2.0

.

now there's one interesting observation:
in windows one can switch OFF the `write-cache buffer flushing`, e.g. for testing purposes.
with this tweak in place the performance of systems with *any* driver is **identical** to those with RST "11.2.0"!

[image: buffer flusshing]

## so here comes the question:

due to the very similar performance one *could* suspect that those older RST drivers are `unintentionally` also filtering out the `FlushFileBuffers`.
and hence the performance improvement is rather `by accident` than by smart driver logic...?

in case it's not: why are the "later" RST drivers (such as 11.7 or 12.9) no longer having such good write performance?

.

---

## PS:

as learned from `fernando` at http://www.win-raid.com/t25f23-Which-are-the-quot-best-quot-Intel-AHCI-RAID-drivers.html:

- the classic RST drivers (up till 11.2.0) consist of one single driver "iaStor.sys".
- the newer generation of RST drivers consist of "iaStorA.sys" plus an addition "SCSI filter driver".

and in my testing those *newer* RST drivers no longer show any performance improvements with this one particular application.

Comment: Any updates or further insight on this? I'm very curious myself!